# Webpublish failing to respect typescript configuration

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

In two separate instances of VS2015 (update2 typescript v1.8). Webpublishing ignores the tsconfig.json settings. Specifically the outDir.

I have a setup like so:

//tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "../dist/",
        "noResolve": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "../../node_modules",
        "../../bower_components",
        "../../typings"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

the tsconfig.json lives in the app\src folder and on save it generates the output into the src\dist folder. This works as expected, when in development mode and allows me to gitignore the src\dist folder and  running `tsc.cmd -p app/src` against the webproject on azure (when using source controll on webslots) will regenerate the js. example input and output below

```
    app\
    app\src\
    app\src\tsconfig.json
    app\src\app.ts
    app\src\controllers\
    app\src\controllers\file1.ts
...
    app\dist\
    app\dist\app.js
    app\dist\controllers\
    app\dist\controllers\file1.js
```

However if i webpublish to a destination server or to a folder on the local filesystem i get an error copying app\src\app.js.

```
Copying file app\src\app.js to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\app\src\app.js failed. Could not find file 'app\src\app.js'.  
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets    Line 2998
```

Line 2998 of Microsoft.web.publishing.targets is

```
<!--Force Copy Of all file to the $(WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder) if needed-->
    <CopyPipelineFiles PipelineItems="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)"
                           SourceDirectory="$(WebPublishPipelineProjectDirectory)"
                           TargetDirectory="$(WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)"
                           SkipMetadataExcludeTrueItems="True"
                           UpdateItemSpec="True"
                           DeleteItemsMarkAsExcludeTrue ="True"
                       Condition="'@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)' != ''">
```

If i change my debug output to verbose and search for app.js in the output i see two instances

```
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe --project "PROJECTNAME\app\src\tsconfig.json"
3>Done executing task "VsTsc".
3>Done building target "PreComputeCompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig" in project "PROJECTNAME.csproj".
3>Target "CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" from project "..PROJECTNAME.csproj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
3>Building target "CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig" completely.
3>Output file "app\src\services\app.js" does not exist.
```

and

```
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2998,5): Error : Copying file app\src\services\app.js to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\app\src\services\app.js failed. Could not find file 'app\src\services\app.js'.
4>Done building project "PROJECTNAME.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

It seems it is expecting the output to be inplace and not respecting the output directory.

**UPDATE**: there is a Github Issue tracking this bug https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6934